# Body text alignment to baseline grid when using paragraph styles

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to set paragraph styles for headings in IdCS6. My leading is 15pt for body text, 30pt for headings. My baseline grid is also set to increment every 15pt.

After the heading paragraph style is used, why doesn't my body text align? The header leading is an increment of the base text leading, so I don't get it.

[image]

Comment: What size is the type? That will have to be in some increment of 15pt as well.

Comment: The type is 28 and 12... but why would that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, figured it out. If H1 and P1 are paragraph styles for headings and body text, then the body text should be *aligned to baseline grid* and the header should be *not aligned to baseline grid*.

[image: aligned to baseline grid]

Comment: Yeah, I was about to post this exact same thing. Good job figuring it out yourself.